# Changing TO email id based on selection in android Intent ACTION_SEND

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-widget

I am developing an android app which sends an email to the different people based on selection made
So I want the TO field of the email to be changed based upon the selection made.

So I am loading the email id into a string called emailaddress after the selections are made

Now I kept as follows

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.setType("application/octet-stream");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL ,emailaddress);
```

But the TO address is being left blank. I confirmed that email address is loading into the string by a toast but it is simply not appearing the TO :(

How to solve this problem?

Thanking You
Yours Sincerely,
ChinniKrishna Kothapalli

Comment: I even tried Shared Preferences to share the mail address but did not work out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in EXTRA_EMAIL, because it accepts only String[] parameter instead String. **Example**:

```
public static void sendMail(Activity activity, String recipient, String subject, String body)
{
    Intent mail_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mail_intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    mail_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient});
    mail_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    mail_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mail_intent, "Preferovaná aplikácia pre zaslanie e-mailu..."));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your initial intent should be ACTION_SENDTO rather simply ACTION_SEND.

ACTION_SEND simply delivers to someone else.
ACTION_SENDTO delivers to someone specified by the data.

Comment: It is giving an error that "No application can perform this action"